# React Native - Dynamic forms and updating state that has an array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, object, react-hooks

How do you handle multiple input fields when its being displayed dynamically and update the input field state based on index.

```
const [state, setState] = useState[{value1: '',  value2: ''}]

const handleValue1 = (index, value) => {
  setState(prevObj => ({
    ...prevObj[index],
    value1: value,
  }));
  console.log(state);
}

const handleValue2 = (index, value) => {
  setState(prevObj => ({
    ...prevObj[index],
    value2: value,
  }));
  console.log(state);
}

return (
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={e => handleValue1(index, e)}
        value={state.value1}
      />

      <TextInput
        onChangeText={e => handleValue2(index, e)}
        value={state.value2}
      />
   />
)
```

There could be multiple TextInput pair, depending on the DATA, how do I dynamically update the values where ultimately I'll have:

```
[0]: {
  value1: 'some value',
  value2: 'another value',  
},
[1]: {
  value1: 'some value from another update',
  value2: 'another value from another update again',  
}
```

The issue is that if I update 1 TextInput, all the TextInput field is being updated with the same number, and then the updated state erases the array, and just keeps 1 object pair.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out...

```
const handleValue1 = (index, value) => {
  state[index] = {...state[index], ['value1']: value};
  /*setState(prevObj => ({
    ...prevObj[index],
    value1: value,
  }));*/
  console.log(state);
}

const handleValue2 = (index, value) => {
  state[index] = {...state[index], ['value1']: value};
  /*setState(prevObj => ({
    ...prevObj[index],
    value2: value,
  }));*/
  console.log(state);
}
```

For if anyone else who might be interested.